# OCI Terraform: How to get IP of all the instances in a compartment as a tuple

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I want to extract IP of all the instances in a compartment. Issue is when I use below data block it gives ID only and than for each ID I need to run another data block to get the IPs. Also, consider we have existing realm - realm1 and new realm realm20. In new realm instance wont exist.

```
Step 1:
data "oci_core_instances" "prod_instances" {
  count = contains(["realm1"], local.realm) ? 1 : 0
  compartment_id = module.identity.prod_compartment_id
}
```

Now it returns ids. I want IPs of all hosts except jump host. Also, for new realm realm20 below step will fail. How to set condition here to avoid issue.

```
Step 2:
compute_instances_id = [for instance in data.oci_core_instances.prod_instances.instances : instance.id if length(regexall("prod-[a-z0-9-]*jump[a-z0-9-]*", instance.display_name)) <= 0]
```

Now number of non jumphost will be either 2 or 3.

```
Step 3:
data "oci_core_instance" "compute_instance_1" {
  instance_id = local.compute_instances_id[0]
}

data "oci_core_instance" "compute_instance_2" {
  instance_id = local.compute_instances_id[1]
}

data "oci_core_instance" "compute_instance_3" {
  count = try(local.compute_instances_id[2], null) == null ? 0 : 1
  instance_id = local.compute_instances_id[2]
}
```

Now above one takes 3 steps to complete for existing realm and fails for new realm. There should be data resource which can return IPs as tuple for a particular compartment with condition display name fits a pattern. So, instead of running data than capture ids and than run again data for IPs, its multiple steps which should be reduced to one. Can someone please help here please. Also, for new realms there wont be any instances so need to set count to not run data for new realms.

Comment: The you have to edit the question and explain what error you get, how to reproduce the issue? Its clear that your question is confusing as it stands now.